# How to show foreign table values in ASP.net MVC Core in ViewComponents

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a modal like below,

```
public int userId{ get; set; }
public string userName{ get; set; }

public int categoryId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("categoryId")]
public virtual category categories { get; set; }
```

and I am using ViewComponents and this is my Invoke method;

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
{
    var users = db.Users.OrderByDescending(x => x.userId);

    return View(users);
}
```

and this is my View Component's cshtml page;

```
@model IEnumerable<users>

@foreach (var user in Model)
{
    <text>
        { label: "@user.userName - @user.categories.categoryName},
    </text>
}
```

but for how, I cannot get the value of category name. When i do, i get 500 internal error.

So how can i get foreign table value inside View Component in ASP.NET MVC CORE.

Thanks.

Comment: Please mention your controller code so that what exactly you are pushing to view able to see???

Comment: @stylishCoder i edited, thanks.

Comment: Below Mentioned coding way worked or not???

Comment: @stylishCoder yes, it works. thanks a lot.

Comment: please upvote my answer so that it will be helpfull for others too thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok do one thing create a viewModel and mention all the columns you required in that ,after that put a join between User and Category table and pass the data like below.
Dummy Query below this way your code surely work..just make changes according to your columns and needs

```
var query = from book in context.BOOKs
            join publisher in context.Publishers
            on book.PublisherId equals publisher.Id
            select new BookModel {
                Id = book.Id,Title=book.Title,
                PublisherName=publisher.Name,Auther = book.Auther,
                Year = book.Year,Price=book.Price
            };
```